# Webpack graphql-tag error: Can't resolve './*.graqhql'

Tags: node.js, webpack, graphql

I'm trying to use `graphql-tag` to import `graphql` queries from `.graphql` files using `webpack`, as described [here](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/frontend/webpacking-your-graphql-documents-bf9697ed259b/).

Thus, my `webpack.config` is looking like this:

```js
{

    // ...

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "graphql-tag/loader",
        }],
    },

    entry: "./index.js",

    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
    },

    mode: "development",

}
```

Executing

```
import signin from "./signin.graqhql";
```

inside `index.js` yields the `webpack` error

```bash
ERROR in ./index.js 1:0-35
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './signin.graqhql' in 'D:\DevOps\Foo\app\src'
resolve './signin.graqhql' in 'D:\DevOps\Foo\app\src'
  using description file: D:\DevOps\Foo\app\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: D:\DevOps\Foo\app\package.json (relative path: ./src/signin.graqhql)        
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\DevOps\Foo\app\src\signin.graqhql doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\DevOps\Foo\app\src\signin.graqhql.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\DevOps\Foo\app\src\signin.graqhql.json doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\DevOps\Foo\app\src\signin.graqhql.wasm doesn't exist
      as directory
        D:\DevOps\Foo\app\src\signin.graqhql doesn't exist
```

I've installed `graphql` and `graphql-tag`.

`signin.graphql` should be fine:

```
mutation Mutation($id: String!, $password: String!) {
    signin(id: $id, password: $password) {
        token,
        user {
            id
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed graphql loader for webpack? [read](https://github.com/samsarahq/graphql-loader)

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but I get the same error, same if I use `@graphql-tools/webpack-loader`

Comment: Ok I'm an idiot: its `graphql` not `graqhql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a typo

```
import signin from "./signin.graqhql";
                                ^*p
```

Easy to miss this one.